# XSLT: To pass variable to xpath

Tags: xml, xslt

In the XSLT, I define a template as bellow:

```
<xsl:template name="AA">
        <xsl:param name="pre_path" />
        <xsl:value-of select="concat($pre_path, 'A/B')" />
</xsl:template>
```

call-template

```
<xsl:call-template name="AA">
    <xsl:with-param name="pre_path" select="'C/'"/>
</xsl:call-template>
```

xml:

```
<C>
 <A>
  <B>Hello world</B>
 </A>
</C>
```

Why the result output is C/A/B, not "Hello world"?

I expect:

```
<xsl:value-of select="C/A/B" />
```

to get "Hello world"

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Because you're concatenating two strings: `C/` and `A/B`. However, I would expect the result to be `C/A/B` and not `C/B/A`. Are you trying to build an xpath and then evaluate it?

Comment: Hi Daniel, yes the result is C/A/B. I want this as xpath to get "Hello world"

Comment: Unless you're using XSLT 3.0 (http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#dynamic-xpath) there is no standard way to evaluate a string as an xpath. There might be an extension function available depending on what your XSLT processor is. (Like http://www.exslt.org/dyn/functions/evaluate/ or http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/index.html#!functions/saxon/evaluate)

Comment: Why don't you back up a bit and explain what exactly is it you are trying to accomplish here - not how you decided to go about it (which cannot work).

Comment: Thanks Daniel for explanations. Thanks Michael for criticizing.

Comment: I was merely asking what do you want to accomplish. If I meant to criticize, you wouldn't be able to mistake it for something else...

Answer (score 0):

Below are a couple of options for how to implement a dynamic XPath that selects the value of the elements that match.

An **XSLT 1.0** stylesheet that uses a recursive template to generate a dynamic XPath, invoked for every element in the document and compared to the concatenated path inside of a predicate filter.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="/">      
        <xsl:call-template name="AA">
            <xsl:with-param name="pre_path" select="'C/'"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="AA">
        <xsl:param name="pre_path"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="//*">
            <xsl:variable name="dynamic-xpath">
                <xsl:call-template name="make-xpath">
                    <xsl:with-param name="context-item" select="."/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:variable>

            <xsl:value-of select="self::*[concat($pre_path,'A/B') = 
                                  $dynamic-xpath]"/>
        </xsl:for-each>    
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="make-xpath">
        <xsl:param name="context-item"/>
        <xsl:param name="path"/>

        <xsl:variable name="new-path">
            <xsl:value-of select="local-name($context-item)"/>
            <xsl:if test="normalize-space($path)">
                <xsl:value-of select="concat('/',$path)"/>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:variable>

        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$context-item/parent::*">
                <xsl:call-template name="make-xpath">
                    <xsl:with-param name="context-item" 
                                    select="$context-item/parent::*"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="path" select="$new-path"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="$new-path"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

An **XSLT 2.0** stylesheet that constructs a dynamic expression and compares it to the value of the concatenated `$pre_path` and static `'A/B'` values inside of a predicate filter for every element in the document.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:call-template name="AA">
            <xsl:with-param name="pre_path" select="'C/'"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="AA">
        <xsl:param name="pre_path"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="//*[concat($pre_path,'A/B') = 
                       string-join(ancestor-or-self::*/local-name(), '/')]"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

An **XSLT 3.0** solution that leverages [`xsl:evaluate`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#evaluation-as-optional-feature) to select items with the dynamic XPath:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:call-template name="AA">
            <xsl:with-param name="pre_path" select="'C/'"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="AA">
        <xsl:param name="pre_path"/>
        <xsl:variable name="items" as="node()*">
            <xsl:evaluate xpath="concat($pre_path,'A/B')"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:value-of select="$items"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```